# How Can I merge 9 sns.displot() pictures into 1 picture?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I want to use `sns.displot()` to plot 9 features's distribution. And I want to merge these 9 pictures into 1 picture to show them clearly. I tried to use

```
name = ['active_users','download','hot_songs','like','pre_plays','rate','sum_initial',
        'w_rate','week_mean']
for i in range(9):
    ax = plt.subplot(3,3,i+1)
    plt.axis('on')
    ax.set_title(name[i])
    ax.plot(sns.distplot(df[name[i]]))
```

In this code, `name` are columns' names and also the features I want to show. And  I will got this error `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number`. I do not know my idea is right or not. Can someone help me?

Comment: You can supply the link to a picture, even being new here. Please be aware that you should provide a clear problem description using a [mcve] of the issue, not necessarily your full data. This allows other users to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib's plotting command `ax.plot()` needs to be called with actual data, not with an axes created by another plotting command. `ax.plot(sns.distplot(df[name[i]]))` therefore makes no sense.

You can use `sns.distplot(df[name[i]], ax=ax)` to plot the seaborn distplot to a specifiy axes `ax`.